# Laravel Relationships: 3 Models

Tags: laravel, eloquent

I have a problem with laravel relationships.

I have 3 models:

City —(hasMany) —>Clinic—(hasMany) —>Stock

Stock —(belongsTo) —>Clinic —(belongsTo) —>City

I need get all cities which has stocks, looks like «Stock->cities». I can write sql-query:

```
SELECT ct.id, ct.name
FROM CfgCity as ct
RIGHT JOIN lr_clinics AS cl ON(ct.id=cl.city_id)
RIGHT JOIN lr_clinic_stocks AS st ON(cl.id=st.clinic_id)
WHERE st.deleted_at IS NULL
GROUP BY ct.id
```

But I want decision in laravel-orm, because it’s more readable and I don’t need write names of rows and tables. Is it possible?
Thanks.

Comment: You need to get better at reading the documentation.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From your question it is clear that `city` has relation with `clinic` and `clinic` has relation with `stock` that means `city` has relation with `stock` through `clinic`. That you can define it using laravel relationship.

> City Model

```
class City extends Model {

    public function clinics(){
       return $this->hasMany(Clinic::class);
    }

    public function stocks(){
       return $this->hasManyThrough(Stock::class, Clinic::class);
    }
}
```

> Fetch data

```
$cities = City::whereHas('stocks')->get();
```

For details you can check https://laravel.com/docs/5.6/eloquent-relationships#has-many-through

Answer (score 0):

alternatively you can use the chaining method,

```
class City extends Model {

    public function clinics(){
       return $this->hasMany(Clinic::class);
    }

}
```

and the clinics model is related to the stocks model

```
class clinic extends Model {

    public function stocks(){
       return $this->hasMany(Stock::class);
    }

}
```

then use the chaining method

fetch data

```
$cities = City::with('clinics.stocks')->get();
```